# Flutter: what's the most performant, seamless way to access SharedPreferences in multiple classes?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

So I call

```
SharedPReference prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

In my parent Main.dart.  Then when the user presses a button in the ButtonBar it gets sent away using

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => Agenda(prefs: prefs,)));
```

I'm concerned this is not the most robust or performant way to use shared Preferences on child screens.  For instance say the user navigated away from Main.dart before I have an instance of SharedPreferences, then the child screen - Agenda.dart - will have `null` passed into it as the value of prefs.

What happens then?  Is the child screen stuck trying to access fields which are null?  When Main.dart async process gets an instance of SharedPreferences does it feed it through to the child screen/class?

Would it be more robust to summon SharedPreferences in every class that uses it?  Using:
`SharedPReference prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

I feel passing prefs around is better because it reduces bottlenecks, but I don't fully understand.

When I modify values in SharedPreferences in child classes, then BACK button to it's parent screen, will the parent screen be accessing an updated SharedPreference, automagically?

Answer (score 0):

`getInstance()` will check `_completer` , because `_completer` is `static` 
the first time execution will keep reference in `SharedPreferences._(this._preferenceCache)` 
the next time you call `getInstance()` will always directly return `_completer.future;` reference  of cache, see picture below
no matter where you call `getInstance()` , even in `SecondRoute`

Source code of `getInstance()`

```
class SharedPreferences {
   SharedPreferences._(this._preferenceCache);
   static Completer<SharedPreferences> _completer;
...
static Future<SharedPreferences> getInstance() async {
    if (_completer == null) {
      _completer = Completer<SharedPreferences>();
      try {
        final Map<String, Object> preferencesMap =
            await _getSharedPreferencesMap();
        _completer.complete(SharedPreferences._(preferencesMap));
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        // If there's an error, explicitly return the future with an error.
        // then set the completer to null so we can retry.
        _completer.completeError(e);
        final Future<SharedPreferences> sharedPrefsFuture = _completer.future;
        _completer = null;
        return sharedPrefsFuture;
      }
    }
    return _completer.future;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What happens then? Is the child screen stuck trying to access fields which are null? When Main.dart async process gets an instance of SharedPreferences does it feed it through to the child screen/class?

This depends on your code. If you await for the SharedPreferences instance and then navigate, it's OK. But if you dont await it, then null will be passed to the next screen and no, it wont be feed through to the child screen/class.

> When I modify values in SharedPreferences in child classes, then BACK button to it's parent screen, will the parent screen be accessing an updated SharedPreference, automagically?

Yes, it will, but not automagically. When you pass an object to another class or function in Dart, actually the object itself is not passed. A reference to that object is passed. A reference to an object is like an address to an object's place in memory.

And generally about your question, you can make use of the [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) and [injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable) packages. get_it is a simple Service Locator for Dart and Flutter projects with some additional goodies and Injectable is a convenient code generator for get_it.

Using these two packages you can register modules, which is a good place for SharedPrefrences. Take a look at [this](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#pre-resolving-the-future) example to learn more about it.

Another way can be making use of an [inherited widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html). You can provide a value to the whole widget tree, and then you can access that value (that in your case would be SharedPrefrences instance) anywhere in your widgets.